# GET http://localhost:3306/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NQfLxAy net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm building a Real time chatbox using Node.js. So right now I just want to display the entered name by the user into the console. But it doesn't do that. Please help me with this, it would be really appreciated.

index.php

```
    <!-- include jquery and socket IO -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/socket.io.js"></script>

<!-- create a form to enter username -->
<form onsubmit="return enterName();">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<script>
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "localhost:3000");
    //creating io instance
    var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");

    function enterName(){
        //get username
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

        //send it to server
        socket.emit("user_connected", name);

        //prevent the form from submiting
        return false;
    }

    //listen from server
    socket.on("user_connected", function (username){
        console.log(username);
    });
</script>
```

server.js

```
    //creating express instance
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

//creating http instance
var http = require("http").createServer(app);

//creating socket io instance
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

io.on("connection", function (socket){
    console.log("User connected", socket.id);

    // attach incoming listener for new user
    socket.on("user_connected", function (username) {
        // save in array
        users[username] = socket.id;

        // socket ID will be used to send message to individual person

        // notify all connected clients
        io.emit("user_connected", username);
    });
});

//start the server
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started");
});
```

The problem is in index.php. Please let me know where you think the problem could be and if possible, you could also try my index.php out and edit it and make it work. Thank You so much! :)

Comment: There is already a native event for client connection, you should use that instead of introducing another event to do the same job. socket.on('connect'). To listen for incoming connection server.on('connection')

Answer (score 1):

```
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started");
});
```

and

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:3306");
```

seem to be using different ports.

Comment: Hey! thanks for observing that. I changed it while doing trial and error and I forgot to notice that. But still, the following error shows up now on console

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NQfPndV' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Failed :3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NQfPndV:1 to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED"

Comment: You must enable CORS on your express server.

Use this to do it: https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Edit: My bad. You're using http. You must send Access Control headers with your response. There are many ways to do it, but the easiest one is: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "your_address")`

Comment: Tnx! I hope this works. Edit: Oh I just read your edited part. Let me try

Comment: whats my address btw? Just to confirm, could you give an example?

Comment: In your example `localhost:3000`

Comment: Andddd now the error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: res is not defined
    at index.php:12"...is there some other way to set the header as 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'?

Comment: You're not supposed to put it in your index.php. Anyway, it has been a while since I've dealt with socket.io. After googling the issue, there is a specific solution in the official documentation: https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/ Try to implement that.